# How to use a function to set a value in a ternary operation?

Tags: javascript, function, return, conditional-operator

There are 3 values,

- `previousBalanceTotal` = It is the total balance in a bank account
- `previousWithdrawTotal` = I've withdrawn this much total value before
- `newWithdrawAmount` = The amount I want to withdraw now,

I need to set `newWithdrawTotal` now.

What i wanna do is,
if my `newWithdrawAmount` is bigger than my `previousBalanceTotal`,
I want to show an alert, and keep the `newWithdrawTotal` as previousWithdrawTotal,
else add the  `newWithdrawAmount` to `previousWithdrawTotal` and keep it in `newWithdrawTotal`.

I tried the following code, but it does not work when `newWithdrawAmount` is greater than `previousBalanceTotal`. It returns a function and doesn't show the alert. Could you please help me to solve this??

```
const newWithdrawTotal = (newWithdrawAmount < previousBalanceTotal) ? (newWithdrawAmount + previousWithdrawTotal) : function () {
    console.log(previousWithdrawTotal);

    alert('you can not withdraw more than your balance');
    return previousWithdrawTotal;
};
console.log(newWithdrawTotal);
```

Comment: why not use an `if` statement?

Comment: A conditional alert within a ternary would be hacky at best.

Comment: I am doing this in a simple javascript project, I need to keep the newWithdrawTotal value as a const and later pass this to another function. So I need to write this way, cause it would be efficient. Can you help me?

Comment: does not make sense when one way you get a number and the other way is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the function, you're just returning it. Use an IIFE to call the anonymous function immediately.

```js
const newWithdrawTotal = (newWithdrawAmount < previousBalanceTotal) ?
  (newWithdrawAmount + previousWithdrawTotal) : (function() {
    console.log(previousWithdrawTotal);

    alert('you can not withdraw more than your balance');
    return previousWithdrawTotal;
  })();
console.log(newWithdrawTotal);
```

You don't really need the function, you can use the comma-operator instead.

```js
const newWithdrawTotal = (newWithdrawAmount < previousBalanceTotal) ? (newWithdrawAmount + previousWithdrawTotal) : (
  console.log(previousWithdrawTotal),
  alert('you can not withdraw more than your balance'),
  previousWithdrawTotal
);

console.log(newWithdrawTotal);
```

Comment: Thanks both of the solutions work fine! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block

```
const newWithdrawAmount = 13000;
const previousBalanceTotal = 12000;
const previousWithdrawTotal = 300;
var newWithdrawTotal;
function calc() {
    if(newWithdrawAmount < previousBalanceTotal) {
        return newWithdrawTotal = newWithdrawAmount + previousWithdrawTotal
    } else {
        console.log(previousWithdrawTotal);
        alert('you can not withdraw more than your balance');
        return newWithdrawTotal = previousWithdrawTotal;
    }
}
calc()
console.log(newWithdrawTotal);
```

Comment: He wants `newWithdrawTotal` to be `const`. Why don't you just return the value from your function, and use `const newWithdrawTotal = calc()`. And while you're at it, the function should take parameters.

Comment: can do both or many more ways. I choose to solve it this way. But there are more ways you can solve it.

Comment: In a comment he says "I need to keep the newWithdrawTotal value as a const".

Comment: oh, I didn't see that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).